# AppleScript folder sync

Tags: applescript

I want to have my Dropbox automatically update when something changes(a new folder is created, or a new file created) in a specific folder in My Documents. I figured that AppleScript was the only way to do this as Dropbox does not have any options that allow this. Could someone please give me some AppleScript that would accomplish this, as I am not very experienced in AppleScript?

Comment: AppleScript is not the only way. [launchd](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html) is another way using `WatchPaths`. When the path is an folder, any changes to the folder will trigger the specified command.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds a bit back-to-front! Put the stuff you want in your Dropbox in your Dropbox and it will stay up-to-date - no need for any Applescript or sync software.

If you have an application that is unaware of Dropbox and insists on writing in a folder within your Documents folder, make a symbolic link from there to Dropbox.

So, make a folder in Dropbox where you really want your stuff:

```
mkdir ~/Dropbox/stuff
```

then make a symbolic link from the other place. Say it is ~/Documents/data, you would do

```
ln -s ~/Dropbox/stuff ~/Documents/data
```

Then anything you put in ~/Documents/data will actually really be in your Dropbox.

Or, if you already have files in ~/Documents/data, use the Finder to drag that and move it into your Dropbox, then just follow the second step above (the one with `ln`).

Comment: The main reason I am using Dropbox is in case I forget a document on my computer at home and I need it at school, so i kinda need it to update

Comment: The above will keep anyhting you put in `Documents/data` automatically updated in your Dropbox. Isn't that what you want? If not, please say exactly what in your Documents folder you would like reflected/updated/kept in your Dropbox.

Comment: So if I have an existing document and I update it, like write something in it, will it still update?

Comment: Yes. Where are the documents you want reflected in your Dropbox?

Comment: In a folder in the Documents folder.

Comment: I tired what you said but i think the order of the directories may be backwards?

Comment: So is it working now? If not, please provide some more information so we can get it sorted out.